# Computation of series $\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_{m-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_{n} \to \infty,\quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{m \to \infty}a_m \to 0,$$

can we say (more preferably prove analytically) that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}a_{m-n} \to \infty.$$ Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're just reversing the order of the finite sum before the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking if

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \left(a_0+a_1+\cdots + a_m\right) = \lim_{m\to\infty} \left(a_m+\cdots + a_1+ a_0\right)$$

This is true just by the associative and commutative properties of addition; they are the limits of equal expressions.

Comment: Reverting the order is some kind of rearrangement. Does the rearranged series also diverge? Can we make any connections with `Riemann’s Rearrangement Theorem`?

Comment: @Thoth: We're rearranging a *finite sum*, not a series.